# How to retrieve values from a form whose label has the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

The html is being appended with the length of the data. since the data length being dynamic appending it through loop. now, i have to recaptured the data from the label since this function is used to edit the details i have to get the value from the label.
but all the label has the same ids

```
function editUserDetails(participant_number){
  $("#editform").html("");
  $("#editdetails").slideDown(300);
  $.each(user_data[participant_number],function(k,v){
    if(k!="discount_code" && k!="payment_id" && k!="ticket_type" && k!="time_stamp" && k!="ticket_status" && k!="booking_id" && k!="misc" && k!="event_name" && k!="ticket_price" && k!="paid_amount")
    {
      $("#editform").append(
        "<label id=\"editnamelabel\">" + removeSpecialCharacter(k) + "  </label>" +
        "<input name=\"name\" type=\"text\" id=\"editname\" value=" + v + ">"
            );
        console.log(k,v);
    }
   });
}
```

Comment: Could you create working minimal example?

Comment: You can distinguish ids appending the `partecipant_number`, or the `k`, or both.